# How do I set provider for polygon mainnet?

Tags: web3js, polygon

If I have metamask installed my code works, but if its not installed I get this error:

```
chovy, [12/12/21 10:58 AM]
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provider not set or invalid
    at Object.InvalidProvider (web3-core-helpers.js:2)
    at r.c.send (web3-core-requestmanager.js:2)
    at k (web3-core-method.js:2)
    at n (web3-core-method.js:2)
    at Object.l._executeMethod (web3-eth-contract.js:2)
    at HTMLElement.getTotal (tip-me.js:92)
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (tip-me.js:256)
```

If I understand correctly I should be able to query a contract without metamask installed...

Here is the code making the error:

```
  async getTotal() {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    const NameContract = new web3.eth.Contract(this.abi, this.contractAddr);
    this.totals = {
      amount: Number(web3.utils.fromWei((await NameContract.methods.getTotalValueProcessed().call()), 'ether')).toFixed(8),
      fees: Number(web3.utils.fromWei((await  NameContract.methods.getFees().call()), 'ether')).toFixed(8),
      released: Number(web3.utils.fromWei((await NameContract.methods.getReleased().call()), 'ether')).toFixed(8)
    };

    console.log('total: ', this.totals);

    await this.render();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't work without Metamask.

The line

> window.ethereum

is trying to get the object that Metamask injects in your browser. If you want it to work without metamask, you'll need a provider like Infura or Alchemy.

Comment: Thanks for that response. Makes sense now. Can't interface with blockchain without metamask.